# Fiscal Month definition in SQL

Tags: sql

Is there a clever way to define a fiscal month using a window function or should I create a stored function to do this ?
Nov : 10/22-11/21
Dec : 11/22-12/21
Jan : 12/22-1/21
etc.

```
Fiscal_Month_Num = GetFiscalMonth('2015-10-01')
```

Comment: A calendar table that actually stores this information has many advantages.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

A calendar/dates table would be my first choice.

That said, and **IF** SQL Server, perhaps something like this

```
Declare @Date date = '2015-10-22'
Select Month(DateAdd(MM,day(@date)/22,@Date))
```

Returns

```
11
```

Comment: Brilliant John...thanks for that.
However, I was able to resolve it with a Date DIM table.

Comment: @Syswizard Certainly the smarter choice.